# Check checklistbox based on data from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I want to check items in a `CheckListBox` based on if value of returned fields from database are the same as the name of the item of the `CheckListBox`.

This is the loop I made:

```
        While (myReader.Read())
            For I = 0 To clbMyBox.Items.Count - 1
                If clbMyBox.Items(I).ToString = myReader.GetString(0) Then
                    clbMyBox.SetItemChecked(I, True)
                End If
            Next
        End While
```

Unfortunately this only checks all checkboxes. I know that the rest works, and that `myReader.GetString(0)` really returns the data I want.

Comment: what is the data returned by `myReader.GetString(0)`?

Comment: It returns a `String` with names in it. So if a checkbox has the value "John" and `myReader.GetString()` returns "John", it will be checked. Now it results in all of them being checked.

Comment: What is the return of `clbMyBox.Items(I).ToString`? Have you forgotten to add the parens: `clbMyBox.Items(I).ToString()`?

Comment: No, `()` is not needed. Got it to work now, problem was somewhere else. Anyway, thanks a lot for assisting!

Comment: If this is solved, please post the solution as an answer for future reference.

Comment: Not really a solution. Just too much code to handle at the moment. :)